# Can USB 3.1 improve USB 3.0 upstream performance?

Tags: usb, display, performance, usb-3, usb-hub

My monitor gives two USB 3.0 ports and two USB 2.0 ports via a single USB 3.0 upstream port. will connecting my display to a USB 3.1 improve the overall performance of USB ports provided on the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the USB version naming is super confusing. USB 3.1 gen 1 is actually exactly the same thing as USB 3.0. They have renamed "3.0" to "3.1 gen 1" when 3.1 was released. "3.2 gen 1" is also the same thing. Unless it has "gen 2" in name, it's the same port with the same speeds.

Assuming that you have 3.1 gen 2 ports in your computer, you'd need 3.1 gen 2 support in your monitor too. It doesn't have it, because it's branded as USB 3.0 (and there was no gen 2 for USB 3.0). So no, plugging it into a faster port won't provide any benefits.